# Doxygen repeating text

Tags: doxygen

In all my APIs I have a line of text that gets repeated. Is there a way to put that text in one place and link to it from the APIs?

For instance, in the below example, how to put the 'text that is common for many APIs' in one place, instead of writing the same thing in all the APIs?

```
/**                                                                            
 * @brief Function description                                        
 * @param [in] param function param description 
 * @return return description                                                         
 *                                                                              
 * @attention text that is common for many APIs
 ***********************************************************************/       
 int func(int param);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is always the same line, best would be to define a special command for it by means of and alias in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile), see the tag `ALIASES`

For longer texts the doxygen command `\includedoc` would be the way to go.